# How to find the change of text based on a unique value on another column in an excel file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a excel file containing three columns as shown below,

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 117 | Laspringe | 2019-04-08 |
| 117 | Laspringe (FT) | 2020-06-16 |
| 117 | Laspringe (Ftp) | 2020-07-24 |
| 999 | Angelo | 2020-04-15 |
| 999 | Angelo(FT) | 2021-03-05 |
| 999 | Angelo(Ftp) | 2021-09-13 |
| 999 | Angelo | 2022-02-20 |

I wanted to find out that based on each ID which has the name changed from original name and changed back to the same original name. For example **Angelo** is changed to **Angelo(FT)**, **Angelo(Ftp)** and changed back to original **Angelo**.

Whereas **Laspringe** is not changed back to the original name.

Is it possible to find out which of the ID's have changed the name back to original using python ??

Expecting the result to be like,

| ID |
| --- |
| 999 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way might be to check if the Name has any duplicate per group:

```
s = df.duplicated(['ID', 'Name']).groupby(df['ID']).any()
out = s[s].index.tolist()
```

Output: `[999]`

If you can have duplicates on successive dates (A -> A -> B shouldn't be a match):

```
s = (df
  .sort_values(by='Date')
  .groupby('ID')['Name']
  .agg(lambda s: s[s.ne(s.shift())].duplicated().any())
)
out = s[s].index.tolist()
```

The two code will behave differently on this input:

```
    ID             Name        Date
0  117        Laspringe  2019-04-08
1  117        Laspringe  2019-04-09 # duplicated but no intermediate name
2  117   Laspringe (FT)  2020-06-16
3  117  Laspringe (Ftp)  2020-07-24
4  999           Angelo  2020-04-15
5  999       Angelo(FT)  2021-03-05
6  999      Angelo(Ftp)  2021-09-13
7  999           Angelo  2022-02-29
```

Comment: It will fails if the name again changes back to something else. You need to consider the Date column also

Comment: @Epsi95 not it won't fail for this reason and I added another approach is the order is important (so that A -> A -> B is not considered a duplicate)

Comment: I tested and it just failed, you need to add `sort_values` step

Comment: @Epsi95 maybe we have a different interpretation of the question. I understood that A -> B -> A -> C should be a match because there was at least one change back to an older name

Comment: you are correct, the question seems vague in that regard.

Comment: @Epsi95, I just have the scenario A->B->C->A , Not the case A->A->B->A.

Comment: What about `A -> B -> A -> C`? do you want to identify it as a match? (my code does)

Comment: @mozway, No, I just have the scenario A->B->C->A, the A is either in 1st and last or else just once.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the columns in an excel sheet using openpyxl.  In this case I've used a defaultdict to build a list of names for each id, and then the final check is that the first and last item in each list are the same.

```
import openpyxl, collections

ws = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx').active
name_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
ids, names = ([cell.value for cell in col] for col in ws.iter_cols(1,2))
for id_, name in zip(ids[1:],names[1:]):  # [1:] to ignore the header row
    name_dict[id_].append(name)
print(*[k for k,v in name_dict.items() if v[0]==v[-1]])
```

Comment: This just returns the unique names which occurs only once.

Comment: With your example spreadsheet I see `999` printed out.  Please note that I have assumed that there *is* a header row, and have removed it.  That could be why you see different behavior.

Comment: Ok, How to change If there is no header row, as it is in a dataframe.

Comment: You can use `groupby` and `agg`regate the dataframe with: `df_agg = df.groupby(df['ID']).agg(list)` and then to check the first and last entries of each list you can use: `s = df_agg['Name'].apply(lambda x: x[0]==x[-1])` to create a series, and then `s[s].index` to return the indices meeting the condition.